# split a polynomial string with more the one delimiter and keep the delimiters? (JAVA)

Tags: java

For example if i got the string `"1+3-2+45-6"`
I need a array of strings `{1,+3,-2,+45,-6}`

I tried to split twice, 1 time with "+" and another time with "-".
but it inconvenient.
There is some easy way in JAVA to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you look in the help under 'string functions'. Then do an attempt, and if that does not work, post your code here + errors. This is not "can you do my work for me?" site.

Answer (score 2):

Use positive lookahead based regex. `(?=[+-])` regex matches the boundary which exists just before to the `+` or `-` symbols. Splitting the input according to the matched boundary will give you the desired output.

```
string.split("(?=[+-])");
```

**Example:**

```
String s = "1+3-2+45-6";
String[] parts = s.split("(?=[+-])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[1, +3, -2, +45, -6]
```

Comment: The result will give only the numbers but not the signs

Comment: **I was wrong.** Thanks for correcting me. I am putting an upvote.

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @SagivMapgavker if you think this answer satisfies you problem then you should accept the answer.